# all Huawei, Honor, Xiaomi on Marshmallow: Notification small icon always set to app icon

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow, huawei-mobile-services

on all Huawei, Honor, Xiaomi with Android Marshmallow (custom ROM for dual SIM), the notification small icon `setSmallIcon` is always set to the default app activity icon, I have not been able to put my own as it should. The large icon `setLargeIcon` is working fine.
Tested API 21 and 23.
Has anyone a working code?

```
test(R.drawable.ic_mynotificon, "Test");

private void test(int resID, String txt)
{
    final NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
    final NotificationCompat.Builder notif_builer = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
        .setContentTitle(txt)
        .setContentText(txt)
        .setSmallIcon(resID)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);

    mNotificationManager.notify(999, notif_builer.build());
    return;
}
```

Comment: What launcher does Huawei uses? Bear in mind that there could be minor differences between the Android build, with the stock AOSP version that is on Nexus devices.

Comment: Yes, seems like their custom layer is called EMUI so I suspect this to contain a bug.

Comment: Small icons are limited to 24x24 ...what size is your icon?

Comment: I've different sizes so I made a new test with a 20x20 white icon and it is still the same.

Comment: Still no solution! Also affecting all HONOR and now spreading to Xiaomi Note 4.